# What is the meaning of the parameter of max_pool2d?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In the `8th` line of code shown below, I don't know the meaning of the second `[2,2]`.

Is it the size of stride? (the API of `max_pool2d` is also shown below) By the way, how did the number `1024` in the `15th` line of code come from?

```py
def build_graph(top_k):
  # with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  keep_prob = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[], name='keep_prob')
  images = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 64, 64, 1], name='image_batch')
  labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[None], name='label_batch')

  conv_1 = slim.conv2d(images, 64, [3, 3], 1, padding='SAME', scope='conv1')
  max_pool_1 = slim.max_pool2d(conv_1, [2, 2], [2, 2], padding='SAME')
  conv_2 = slim.conv2d(max_pool_1, 128, [3, 3], padding='SAME', scope='conv2')
  max_pool_2 = slim.max_pool2d(conv_2, [2, 2], [2, 2], padding='SAME')
  conv_3 = slim.conv2d(max_pool_2, 256, [3, 3], padding='SAME', scope='conv3')
  max_pool_3 = slim.max_pool2d(conv_3, [2, 2], [2, 2], padding='SAME')

  flatten = slim.flatten(max_pool_3)
  fc1 = slim.fully_connected(slim.dropout(flatten, keep_prob), 1024, activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh, scope='fc1')
  logits = slim.fully_connected(slim.dropout(fc1, keep_prob), FLAGS.charset_size, activation_fn=None, scope='fc2')
  # logits = slim.fully_connected(flatten, FLAGS.charset_size, activation_fn=None, reuse=reuse, scope='fc')
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), labels), tf.float32))
```

Here is the API of `max_pool2d`:

```py
@add_arg_scope
  def max_pool2d(inputs,
    kernel_size,
    stride=2,
    padding='VALID',
    data_format=DATA_FORMAT_NHWC,
    outputs_collections=None,
    scope=None):
```

Comment: please read the documentation of max_pool2d: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool2d

Comment: 1024 is the number of nodes in the fully connected net

Answer (score 0):

The second `[2,2]` in `max_pool2d` specifies the strides of the layer along the x-axis and the y-axis respectively.

Also, the `1024` number in the `fully_connected` function specifies the number of the neurons in that layer.

I would clarify that the number of the neurons of the `fully_connected` layer is not related to the strides of the `max_pool2d` layer. The size of the `fully_connected` layer can be set arbitrarily without considering its input size. Typically, the output layer size or the number of the classes in the problem should be considered while deciding about the number of the last `fully_connected` layers in the networks rather than the layer's input size.